# Does a pedestrian walk 'in' the road, or 'on' the road (both are correct, but which is right?)

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, in-on

Having a bit of a debate about this with some foreign colleagues of mine.

I've always used the phrase 'I'm walking in the road', they think that you should say 'I'm walking on the road'..

I'm not 100% sure why I use the word 'in', but there must be a reason for it!

So... which is right?

Comment: The life I love is makin' music with my friends, and I can't wait to get in the road again.

Comment: Jokes aside, don't know about pedestrians, but there sure is [a *cow* in the road!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lyorl.png) (Courtesy of tchrist in chat.)

Comment: _Both are correct, but which is right_?! I think we might have more serious problems here...

Comment: ........Pardon?

Comment: If "both are correct", then **both are right**: That's elementary logic, my dear Watson. It just depends on where you are or what brand of English you speak. I'd say "There's a cow **in the middle of** the road" but "There's a cow **on the road**. Maybe the cow **on the road** is roadcow. Maybe the cow **in the middle of the road** is trotting around looking for a _torero_ to terrorize.

Comment: There's a bulldozer where the road used to be.

Comment: If you're sure both are correct, where is the detailed context that might show which is right?

I know no rule yet I suggest 'on the road' is purely about the act of walking on a(ny) physical surface. In that way, the two are inextricably linked 

By contrast 'in' the road is about the legal description of what constitutes a road.

Answer (score 7):

Using the preposition *in* vis-à-vis " the road" normally describes an action that takes place in such a way that the normal progress of the thoroughfare might be blocked, or which calls attention to the act in progress.

Take, for example, the Beatles song "Why don't we do it in the road?" Here it means doing something (i.e., fornicating) right out there in front of everybody in such a way that people will stop and take notice. The Beatles were a British band, so that should put paid to any notion that *in* means something different in BrE.

To simply walk in the road means to put oneself in some danger from traffic.

> He was walking in the road, officer. I didn't see him until it was too late.

Normally, to describe the simple act of using the road for pedestrian traffic alongside vehicular traffic, the prepositions *up*, *down*, or *along* are commonly used. They don't carry the connotation of mortal danger, though that may exist as well.

To walk *on* the road describes the relationship of one's feet to the road surface.

Comment: In Yorkshire dialect "in the road" means in the way/blocking something - even if there is no road involved

Comment: @mgb I can vouch for that, and in Yorkshire you would say "Get out of the road" meaning "Get out of my way", regardless of where you were - no actual roads need to be involved.

Comment: @Mynamite I remember that usage from when I lived in the good old 'Black Country'.  Note to non-brits, 'Black Country ' is explained here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Country

Answer (score 1):

Without going into either analyses of why we use these particular prepositions or rigorously obtained and analysed statistics showing frequency of usage of given variants, examining a series of Google Ngrams shows fairly conclusively that

1. Choice of preposition is not prescribed.
2. Choice of preposition changes over time.
3. Choice of preposition within similar structures is idiosyncratic.

Look at Ngrams for **in the X, on the X**

where X =

road, street, lane, avenue, boulevard.

*On the motorway* and *on the slip road* are probably mandatory.

Admittedly, the Ngrams provide only ballpark figures: *on the Crescent* would only be used for a property or disturbance, say, referring not just to the road surface.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments, OP's concepts of "right/correct" aren't helpful here. Lots of prepositions are valid, depending on context. Here are some *estimates* from Google Books for [he walked xxxx the road](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20walked%20up%20the%20road%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)... **down**:18100 **along**:15400 **up**:8020 **on**:7700 **across**:5710 **into**:663 **over**:437 **in**:5

I immediately recognise a problem with those figures - as a native speaker, I know perfectly well that **on**, for example, isn't particularly common for that particular search text. But estimates in GB are skewed according to how often various subsections of the text occur anywhere in the corpus *(walked on, on the, on the road, etc.)*. Here are the values after scrolling through to establish how many *actual* instances occur...

**along**:123(95)
**down**:104(109)
**up**:56(77)
**across**:59(70)
**over**:20(29)
**into**:25(7)
**on**:19(16)
**in**:5(3)

Obviously *across, over* are used in the context of getting from one side of the road to the other, and *into* for stepping off the sidewalk on to the tarmac traffic surface. In the context of *using the road to get somewhere by foot*, we normally use *along, down, up*.

I don't think it's worth differentiating between *on, in*. Almost every actual instance is equivalent with either, and usually would be better replaced by *along, down, up*.

Comment: There's also the concept of "on the road" meaning "to be on the move" or "touring" - the Rolling Stones are on the road, ie on tour. However you wouldn't use this with "walking" as in OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

We would normally say *on*. "In the road" suggests that you are talking about something in the material of the paving itself ("there are layers of concrete and tarmac in the road").

You might say "walking in the middle of the road" because the *in* places you between the two sides of the road, while *on* places you on top of the surface.

Comment: "Percy stepped off the pavement to walk in the road and got run over." *In* is fine here.

Comment: Agreed, the *in* again places the pedestrian between the two sides.

Comment: "In the road" would only be recognised as having the 1st connotation Jon suggests if there was a prior clue (eg you were discussing construction techniques). More usually, the connotation of being 'in the way' or at least 'not where it "should" be' is more likely to be picked up - there's a settee (or, as tchrist/Reg say, cow) in the road. _In_ would be more common here if one were walking there, avoiding still-icy pavements. _On_ would be far more likely if one were discussing driving (keep on the road!) and mandatory if using a transparent metaphor (we've been on the road for six days now).

Comment: -1: *nobody* would normally infer "in the road" to imply the road making materials.

Comment: @horatio I don't mean that they'd infer that, I mean they'd hear something other than what was usual, assume it meant "on the road" and it'd sound wrong. Andrew and Edwin do both give good examples of where it would indeed be used, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing the road as a surface, as a physical material, then things are "on" it: there is snow on the road, oil on the road, a dead animal on the road.

If you are discussing the road as means of transportation, then things are "in" it: there is a bump in the road, a tree in the road, a dead animal in the road.

A dead animal on the road might actually be lying on the very edge of the road; a dead animal in the road is *in your way*.

A pedestrian is on the road from his own point of view: he is literally walking upon the road.

A pedestrian is in the road from a motorist's point of view: he is blocking the road.

Utterly separate from all of the this, the expression "on the road" means "in motion" or "on a trip" as in the exhortation "Let's get this show on the road" or the title of Jack Keroac's famous memoirs *On The Road*.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know what country you are in, as you have not specified it in your profile, and have not carried out a person by person check on the commentators. But, I suspect that "... in the road ..." is Yankee Speak and that the Queen's English would not allow of it. My suspicion may be unfounded :-)

I'm a New Zealander -  we speak the Queen's English here, albeit in a somewhat mangled form. I do not think I have heard "in" used in that manner this century and probably not for half way back though last century either.

Comment: I suspect that what you speak in New Zealand is New Zealand English.

Comment: I'm from England; I did however wonder if there was a possibility of the differing use being a regional thing - even within one country.

Comment: @BarrieEngland - We SPEAK NZ English (ie pronunciation) but largely write British English - spelling and most usage. Much closer to Queen's English than President's English. All will be pleased to know that linguistic pronunciation drift is such that in time Queen's English will be spoken as we speak it now. I'm told. We are just the forerunners. || Would downvoter please explain reason. I really really do not mind downvotes on this sort of thing as long as they are logical - and I'd like to know why for future guidance.

Comment: 'Queen's English' is an imprecise term, and not one used by serious linguists. Not my downvote, by the way. Downvoters seldom explain themselves.

Comment: @BarrieEngland - QE is a good enough term for we non-serious linguists. Few would not know what it meant with some precision in this context.  We know what we speak and what those US fellows speak, and it's not the same (in part), whereas NZ English is very very largely indistinguishable from English English. We have some additional words due to different culturual inputs but no spellings are NZ specific or other than you'd find in England AFAIK. (I say England to be safe - I'll not guarantee our conformance with Welsh or scottish or Irish (either part) local practice).

Comment: What do New Zelander republicans speak?

Comment: @JonHanna - we don't have any worth mentioning. We have two main political parties National & Labour, which very very roughly align with Republican and Democrat. And we have a number of smaller parties who are represented in parliament under our proportional voting system. All our politicians speak New-Zealand-speak BUT the general public perception is that they tend to talk it out of the side of their mouths. That may or may not be unfair, but it's how it is seen to be.

Answer (score -3):

It is "On the road" not "In the road".

Comment: You should add some explanation as to why you believe this is true.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=walk+on+the+road%2Cwalk+in+the+road&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwalk%20on%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwalk%20in%20the%20road%3B%2Cc0